# GKE replacement is forced despite no change in code?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a Terraform code to create a GKE cluster in GCP. Here is my code:

```
resource "google_container_cluster" "abc_cluster" {
    name                = var.gke_cluster_name
    location            = "us-west1"
    project             = var.project_id
    enable_autopilot    = true
    depends_on          = [null_resource.wait_for_artifact_registry_api]
    deletion_protection = false

    vertical_pod_autoscaling {
        enabled = true
    }

   node_config {
       oauth_scopes = [
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
       ]
       reservation_affinity {
           consume_reservation_type = "NO_RESERVATION"
       }
   }

   dns_config {
      cluster_dns = "CLOUD_DNS"
   }

   addons_config {
      http_load_balancing {
      disabled = false
      }
   }
}
```

When I generate "terraform plan" I see this:

```
~ oauth_scopes = [ # forces replacement
          - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
          - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
          - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
          - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
          - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
          - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append",
          + "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
        ]
```

I am unsure why this keeps happening ? Why is Terraform trying to delete from oauth_scopes when I haven't even added it in my code or when it doesn't exist in my statefile ? My ".tfstate" statefile is in line with what my code has. Here is my statefile :

```
"oauth_scopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],
"preemptible": false,
"reservation_affinity": [
    {
       "consume_reservation_type": "NO_RESERVATION",
       "key": "",
       "values": null
    }
]
```

I have tried adding all of following in my oauth_scopes, but it doesn't help my case:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
```

I am not sure where is "diff" coming from ? Can anyone help me understand what is happening please ?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve cluster recreation I recommend to move config from ‘node_config’ to ‘node_pool’ see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/container_cluster#node_pool for details.

Don't be frightened by that output. Probably it was set on the cluster manually or by default for some reason, not via terraform.

`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` grants access to all API, so if this is what you want just apply it.
Moving to node pool should also fix that problem.

Comment: Problem is that with cloud-platform role already being in the code, every time I deploy my code, deployment is slow because TF redeploys GKE cluster again which takes quite a bit of time. Thoughts on why this could be happening please ?

Comment: Do you have ‘google_container_node_pool’ defined? Check my updater answer.

Comment: I don't have a node_pool. Will try this.